# Can 720! be written as the difference of two positive integer powers of 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponentiation, factorial

Does the equation:
$$3^x-3^y=720!$$
have any positive integer solution?

Comment: is that 720 factorial.

Comment: @user258250: yes

Comment: @user258250: it is 720! not 720 marely

Comment: There aren't many possibilities.  Clearly $x \gt y$ and $y$ is the number of factors of 3 in $720!$, which we count to be $y = 356$.

Comment: I suspect there's a nice solution looking at the ternary (or in general, base-$b$) form of $n!$.

Comment: @R.. My second answer could be modified to use ternary expansion.

Comment: @R..: And my answer basically argues that the last nonzero ternary digit of $720!$ is $1$ whereas the last nonzero ternary digit of $3^x-3^y$ is $2$, so they can never be equal.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I didn't mean to imply that it doesn't, just that ternary provides a nice intuitive way for non-mathematicians to think about it.

Comment: @R.. Are you sure a non-mathematician will find using ternary intuitive?

Comment: @Angew: I was thinking (common on SE sites) people with computer programming background as well as people with casual/hobbyist interest in math.

Answer (score 33):

As alex.jordan writes, $3^x-3^y$ factors as $3^y(3^{x-y}-1)$, so $y$ must be the number of factors of $3$ in $720!$.

I don't actually need to count the number of $3$s in $720!$, so let's just define the notation $720!_3$ for "$720!$ with all of the powers of $3$ divided out". This must yield the other factor $3^{x-y}-1$, so we need to investigate whether $720!_3$ is one less than a power of $3$. To do this we will compute it modulo $3$.

In general we have that
$$ (3k)!_3 \equiv (1\cdot 2)^k \cdot k!_3 \equiv (-1)^k k!_3 \pmod 3 $$
And therefore

$$ \begin{align} 720!_3
\equiv 240!_3 
&\equiv 80!_3 \equiv 80\cdot 79 \cdot 78!_3 \equiv - 78!_3 \\
&\equiv -26!_3 \equiv -26\cdot 25 \cdot 24!_3 \equiv 24!_3 \\
&\equiv 8!_3 \equiv 8\cdot 7\cdot 6!_3 \equiv -6!_3 \\
&\equiv -2!_3 \equiv -2 \equiv 1 &\pmod 3
\end{align}$$
which is not one less than a multiple of 3, so certainly not one less than a *power* of $3$.

So the answer is no.

Comment: Can you please explain the first congruence? I don't see where the $2^k$ came from

Comment: @Begi: The factors in $(3k)!$ that are _not_ multiples of $3$ are $$ 1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot8 \cdots (3k-2)\cdot(3k-1) \equiv \underbrace{1\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdots 1\cdot 2}_{k\text{ repeats of }1\cdot 2} \equiv 2^k \pmod 3$$

Comment: In general when $p$ is an odd prime we have $$ (p^nk)!_p \equiv (-1)^k (p^{n-1}k)!_p \pmod{p^n} $$ thanks to [Gauß's generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization) of Wilson's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This was a really nice solution!

Answer (score 10):

If $$720!=3^x-3^y=3^y\left(3^{x-y}-1\right)$$ and since the power of $3$ dividing $720!$ is $$\left\lfloor\frac{720}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{720}{9}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{720}{27}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{720}{81}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{720}{243}\right\rfloor=240+80+26+8+2=356\text{,}$$ it would have to be that $y=356$.

So it remains to see if $3^x-3^{356}=720!$ has an integer solution in $x$.

---

Side note: we can get a good approximation to $\log_3(720!)$ using Stirling's formula with one more term than is typically used: $$\log_3(720!)\approx\frac{1}{\ln3}\left(720\ln(720)-720 +\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi\cdot720)\right)\approx3660.3\ldots$$ Since the terms in Stirling's formula are alternating after this, we can deduce that this is correct to the tenths place. Values of $\ln(3)$, $\ln(720)$, and $\ln(2\pi)$ are easy to calculate by hand to decent precision if needed.

---

$720!$ is a lot bigger than $3^{356}$. Since  $\log_3(720!)\approx3660.3$, in base $3$, $720!$ has $3661$ digits (trigits?), where as $3^{356}$ just has $357$. So $\log_3(720!+3^{356})$ and $\log_3(720!)$ must be very close together. Since the latter is $\approx3660.3$ though, it's not possible for the former to be an integer.

More formally, $$\log_3(720!)<\log_3(720!+3^{356})=x=\log_3(720!)+\log_3\mathopen{}\left(1+\frac{3^{356}}{720!}\right)\mathclose{}<\log_3(720!)+\frac{1}{\ln(3)}\frac{3^{356}}{720!}$$

$$3660.3\ldots<x<3660.3\ldots$$

and there is no integer $x$ between the values on the two ends.

Comment: It doesn't http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=frac%28log_3%28720%21%2B3%5E356%29%29%3D0

Comment: An alternative to the second part would be to see if $\frac{720!}{3^{356}}$ can possibly be one less than a power of $3$, by computing it modulo $3$. I get $$ \frac{720!}{3^{\text{all}}} \equiv 2^{240}\cdot 2^{80} \cdot 80\cdot 79\cdot 2^{26}\cdot 25\cdot 25 \cdot 2^8 \cdot 8\cdot 7 \cdot 2^6 \cdot 2\cdot 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$ which cannot be $3^{x-y}+1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's probably better, since I don't see an easy way to compute $\log_3(720!)$ without computer assistance.

Comment: @HenningMakholm FWIW, I think I've added enough so that a computer wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

## Factorization alternative:

Suppose 
$$\begin{align}
720!&=3^x-3^y\\
&=3^y(3^{x-y}-1)\\
&=3^y(3-1)(3^{x-y-1}+3^{x-y-2}+\cdots+1)\text{.}
\end{align}
$$

Since $720!$ is divisible by $4$, the rightmost factor is even, which means it has an even number of terms, and $$720!=3^y(3-1)(3+1)(3^{x-y-2}+3^{x-y-4}+\cdots+1)$$ The rightmost factor must still be even, given how super-even $720!$ is, so $$720!=3^y(3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^{x-y-4}+3^{x-y-8}+\cdots+1)$$ And again: $$720!=3^y(3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^{x-y-8}+3^{x-y-16}+\cdots+1)$$

We can keep extracting factors of the form $3^{2^k}+1$. Except for $3+1$, none of these factors are divisible by $4$. So we can do this many ($13$) times without exhausting the large power of $2$ that divides $720!$:

$$720!=3^y(3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)\cdots(3^{8192}+1)(3^{x-y-16384}+3^{x-y-32768}+\cdots+1)$$

But this is now ridiculous. The left side is clearly smaller than $729^{720}=3^{4320}$. While the right side is larger than $3^{8192}$.

---

## Basically the same, but using base-$3$

Exponents are all base ten. Also, $N_{10}$ is base ten. All other numbers are base three. In what follows, each step where an additional factor is factored out, the factorization is justified because the large power of $2$ dividing $720!$ implies that the rightmost factor (with the overbrace) has an even number of $1$s.

$$\begin{align}
(10)^{4320}
&=(1000000)^{720}\\
&=729_{10}^{720}\\
&>720_{10}!\\
&=3_{10}^x-3_{10}^y\\
&=(10)^x-(10)^y\\
&=\overbrace{2\cdots2}^{x-y}\overbrace{0\cdots0}^y\\
&=2(10)^y\overbrace{11\cdots11}^{x-y}\\
&=2(10)^y(11)\overbrace{0101\cdots0101}^{x-y}\\
&=2(10)^y(11)(101)\overbrace{00010001\cdots00010001}^{x-y}\\
&=2(10)^y(11)(101)(10001)\overbrace{0000000100000001\cdots0000000100000001}^{x-y}\\
&=\cdots\\
&=2(10)^y(11)(101)(10001)\cdots(\overbrace{10\cdots01}^{8193})\overbrace{0\cdots1\cdots0\cdots1}^{x-y}\\
&>\overbrace{10\cdots01}^{8193}\\
&>\overbrace{10\cdots00}^{8193}\\
&=(10)^{8182}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Interesting how your solutions aim for a contradiction from the _sizes_ of the numbers involved, whereas I'm looking at the ternary expansons from the _least significant_ end ...

Answer (score 2):

Let's write $n=x-y$.  If $720!=3^x-3^y=3^y(3^n-1)$, then $3^n-1$ is divisible by the primes $17$, $31$, $43$, and $79$ (among others, of course).  [As it happens,](https://oeis.org/A001123) $3$ is a primitive root for those primes.  This means that $n$ is divisible by $16$, $30$, $42$, and $78$, hence by the lcm of these, or

$$16\cdot15\cdot7\cdot39=65{,}520$$

But this is vastly larger than $\log_3(720!)\approx3660$.  Thus $720!$ is not the difference of two powers of $3$.